# Mostrar meses continuos en vez de mes por mes o mostrar dos meses en CalendarView de Android

Tags: android, android-layout, calendar

He intentando de todo y no logro mostrar este `CalendarView` de forma continua.

Me muestra un solo mes y para ver los otros meses tengo que hacer `Scroll` hacia abajo. En un teléfono móvil la mitad de la pantalla queda en blanco y da la impresión de estar desaprovechada.

Yo quiero que me llene toda la pantalla con la máxima cantidad de meses completos que puedan entrar, o que me llene la pantalla completa con dos meses.

Este es mi XML actual:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_tercia"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/txt_salterio"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="org.deiverbum.liturgiacatolica.CalendarioActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_tercia">
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <CalendarView
            android:id="@+id/calendarView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**¿Alguna solución que evite el poner límites de fecha (no quisiera añadir restricciones al calendario)?**

Comment: Algo como esto? [Android Calendar View. Months displayed continuously](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38301684/3045491)

Comment: @lois6b probé lo que dice primero, poner `wrap_content`. Lo de poner fechas mínimas y máximas me parece una solución algo restrictiva.

Answer (score 0):

Buenas noches, porque no utilizas dos CalendarView y lo sincronizas.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.gustavo.calendarview.MainActivity">

    <CalendarView
            android:id="@+id/calendarView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <CalendarView
        android:id="@+id/calendarView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Gracias Gustavo. Yo necesito mostrar un menú contextual cuando una fecha sea seleccionada y llamar otra parte de la App usando esa fecha. Tener dos calendarios sería duplicar código. Me extraña que no haya una forma más fácil de mostrar dos meses al mismo tiempo.